# Signed decimal from a signed hex short in python

Tags: python, binary, hex, signed

I was wondering if theres any easy and fast way to obtain the decimal value of a signed hex in python.

What I do to check the value of a hex code is just open up python in terminal and type in the hex, it returns the decimal like this:

```
>>>0x0024
36
>>>0xcafe
51966
```

So I was wondering, is there any way that I could do that for signed short hex? for example **0xfffc** should return **-4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use NumPy numerical types you could use `np.int16` type conversion

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.int16(0x0024)
36
>>> np.int16(0xcafe)
-13570
>>> np.int16(0xfffc)
-4
>>> np.uint16(0xfffc)
65532
>>> np.uint16(0xcafe)
51966
```

Python Language specifies a unified representation for integer numbers, the [`numbers.Integral`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral) class, a subtype of `numbers.Rational`. In Python 3 there are no specific constraints on the range of this type. In Python 2 only the minimal range is specified, that is `numbers.Integral` should have at least the range of  -2147483648 through 2147483647, that corresponds to the 32 bit representation.

NumPy implementation is closer to the machine architecture. To implement numeric operations efficiently it provides [fixed width datatypes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html), such as `int8`, `int16`, `int32`, and `int64`.

Answer (score 5):

```
import ctypes

def hex2dec(v):
    return ctypes.c_int16(v).value

print hex2dec(0xfffc)
print hex2dec(0x0024)
print hex2dec(0xcafe)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `int` classmethod `from_bytes` and provide it with the bytes:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xfc\xff', signed=True, byteorder='little')
-4
```

Comment: Thank you, I think will be useful as well but the answer from dmitri will work in a much simpler way, I'll keep this in mind for when I try to obtain the value for signed chars, really useful but a bit too lenghty

Comment: The best method here. Not only does it only use builtins but also it accepts input from a byte string.